# Disable or change audio ducking (lowering)?

Tags: notifications, settings, audio, 8.1-oreo

The audio ducking feature seems to let apps decide to lower its volume or pause playback while a notification from another app is playing.

Even though this feature is turned on by default, I am unable to find a way to change the amount by which the volume is lowered (similar to how this could be done on any decent OS for PC). Or to just disable this feature.

Most answers to this question on the internet have been utilizing the fallacy that you should mute the notifications if you don't want them to interrupt your playback (of let's say, music).

Obviously I do not need this accessibility feature. I can separate sound sources just fine. Last time I checked this is one of the basic cognitive skills that most humans possess, but maybe I have superpowers after all.

I think it is clear what I want to achieve. No messing with the audio levels unless I say so. A user that is in control, is a happy user. I want to be happy too :(

There is probably no setting to do this. Since I am a developer myself, I wonder if there is some hackish way to modify the default audio ducking volume to simply 100%? Or just using something similar to 'about:config' / windows regedit for Android?

Comment: There is a method here (not tried by me) https://www.xda-developers.com/pokemon-go-audio-focus/

Answer (score 2):

On Android MIUI 12.5.4 I found the option at:

Sound & Vibration > Sound Assistant -> Multiple Audio Sources (don't adjust media volume during incoming notifications or while audio from other source is played)

This made notifications play at normal volume when I was listening to music, and more importantly, no audio ducking.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure on Android 8.1, but on Android 5.1, it's the following:

1. Sound & Notification Settings > Interruptions

   > [image: Enter Sound & Notification settings]
2. Disable Interruptions on specific apps or all together

   > [image: disable interrupts]

Comment: Does this actually do what I want? I just want notification to play during music playback, with the given volumes. Btw, this never happened on my previous Android, I think there might have been a setting to change this on that. The awful thing is that this happened after an upgrade that Android said cannot be undone due to policy updates.

Comment: Looks like "Interruptions" is another name for "Do Not Disturb"? AFAIK, it blocks the notifications completely, not lowering the notification volume only.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by turning do not disturb on and off again to be honest- Android 11