# WhatsApp Call Lowers Media Volume

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, audio, calls, media-player

The volume of the media I'm trying to watch is automatically lowered when I enter a WhatsApp call. The position on the slider does not change so it appears to be the correct volume, but it is noticeably lower.

Any ideas on how to remedy this? Either by restoring the correct volume or lowering call volume below the minimum would be preferable.

Phone Model: Oppo Find X5 Lite,

Android Version: 13,

Comment: This looks like audio ducking. We have an existing question about [Disable or change audio ducking (lowering)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204153/44325), consider checking it. Otherwise, you might want to try searching for similar keywords in the Settings.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable or change audio ducking (lowering)?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/204153/disable-or-change-audio-ducking-lowering)

Comment: Unfortunately those do not answer my questions. They either do not work or I don't have the settings they talk about on my Android version. Thank you though.

And thank you for bringing the name to my attention, I was not aware it was called that and it should make figuring this out easier.